# Why does Ubuntu 14.04 not detect my Wacom Bamboo Pad CTH-301K (USB)?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bamboo, detect

When I plug in my tablet it does nothing and it is not detected by Wacom Tablet mode in Settings.

I have already read tons of different threads, I have installed the Kernel Driver, and X Driver from this page http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads and created a file etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf exactly the same like this one here http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/ci/master/tree/conf/50-wacom.conf

There is no result. The only trace that the tablet is plugged in is that when I write lsusb in the terminal, the output is:

`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 094: ID 056a:0318 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 039: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b302 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Please, help! I don't want to waste my money!

Answer (score 1):

See [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04/531188#531188)

Also, that page is for a Wacom Bamboo with a reference number of 0319 showing up in `lsusb`. The output from `lsusb` for my Bamboo CTH 301K showed as 0318. This means I had to alter the Grub line accordingly (I used 0x318 instead of 0x319 next to the 0x56a bit...)