# Wacom Bamboo CTH-300 not recognized Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, wacom, input-devices

I recently got the Wacom Bamboo tablet (CTH-300) and, obviously, I wanted to try it out!

So, I plugged it in...and nothing happened. I tried changing USB ports - nothing.

I checked out the Wacom tablet settings and the Bluetooth settings - they both show nothing:

**Wacom:**

[image: wacom]

**Bluetooth:**

[image: btooth]

So, I figured it's a drivers issue, and came across [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1265714).

It mentions adding the line `sbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0319:0x40000000` to `/etc/default/grub` and the line `MatchIsTablet "on"` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf`.

However, doing this didn't help - and I don't believe that solution works for the Wacom CTH-300 either.

Here's the output of `dmesg | grep [Ww]acom`: 
`[  262.474974] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom`

And the output of `lsmod | grep [Ww]acom1`: 
`wacom 62856  0`. Note, I had to `modprobe wacom` because when I first boot it comes back with nothing.

`lsusb | grep [Ww]acom` comes back with nothing.

I also tested this on my Ubuntu 14.10 x86 laptop - nothing.

**EDIT**: Found [this blog post](https://cwcode.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/compiling-a-new-kernel-module-to-use-hid-core-for-a-wacom-bamboo-pad/) - not exactly something I want to attempt, but just figured I'd post it.

Comment: Note, here's the full `dmesg` output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9650942/

Comment: Theres a better description of the 'fix' in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/531188/283721) - you may have to modify the `usbhid.quicks` line to match your specific computer.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks for posting that, I hadn't seen that one before. Issue is, I get nothing from lsusb that's even remotely related to Wacom - which makes me think that it's the dongle that's having issues.