# Wacom Bamboo USB (CTH-301) not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: usb, touchpad, wacom

Just bought a Wacom Bamboo. Did try and search to see if people where having trouble using this device under Linux and my results where positive. 
My luck that device is slightly changed and no longer works.
Read a lot of different solutions for different Ubuntu versions and Wacom devices.

So far I detected that the device works correctly. Leds are blinking (good start right?).

`lsusb` returns:

```
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 056a:0318 Wacom Co., Ltd
...
```

The module (`lsmod | grep -i wacom`) returns:

```
wacom                  81920  0 
hid                   110592  3 wacom,hid_generic,usbhid
```

So that all works. I found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04) where someone mentions a kernel bug. I tried it but does not add anything. I do keep the change as it does not have any bad side effects (you never know if it actually does help later on).

I also tried creating (because it's not there on a clean install) an xorg.conf as was sugested on [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom). That did not work as well.

After that I tried the logs and found the following:

```
[    17.865] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom HID Pen'
[    17.865] (**) Wacom HID Pen: always reports core events
[    17.865] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event11"
[    17.920] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
[    17.920] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
[    17.920] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
[    17.920] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
[    17.920] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'pad' for this device.
[    17.920] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: No type specified
[    17.928] (EE) PreInit returned 8 for "Wacom HID Pen"
[    17.928] (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
[    17.928] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom HID Pen (/dev/input/event12)
[    17.928] (**) Wacom HID Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom class"
[    17.928] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom HID Pen'
[    17.928] (**) Wacom HID Pen: always reports core events
[    17.928] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event12"
[    17.984] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
[    17.984] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
[    17.984] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
[    17.984] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
[    17.984] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'pad' for this device.
[    17.984] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: No type specified
[    17.992] (EE) PreInit returned 8 for "Wacom HID Pen"
[    17.992] (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
[    17.992] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom HID Pen (/dev/input/event13)
[    17.992] (**) Wacom HID Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom class"
[    17.992] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom HID Pen'
[    17.992] (**) Wacom HID Pen: always reports core events
[    17.992] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event13"
[    18.048] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
[    18.048] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
[    18.048] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
[    18.048] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
[    18.048] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: Invalid type 'pad' for this device.
[    18.048] (EE) Wacom HID Pen: No type specified
[    18.060] (EE) PreInit returned 8 for "Wacom HID Pen"
[    18.060] (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
```

The logs suggest that the udev rules are not detecting the Wacom input devices as they should be.

Does anybody have any suggestions as where to fix these wrong settings?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that a later kernel update provided the fix.

Comment: Yes, it works in my up to date Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system with the xenial kernel series (now 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu).