# Can we install windows wacom driver for CTH300 and use via wine

Tags: wine, wacom, bamboo

Seems like no support in ubuntu for wacom bamboo as evident from here [How to get Bamboo Pad working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04), and all the suggested workarounds only allowed the pointer movement. So can we install windows driver and use via wine?

Comment: Probably not; `wine` is a user level emulator. Maybe it could be possible to use virtualbox or something like that (a full emulator). But best thing would be to try to contact the wacom driver developers and help them supporting the tablet...