# Wacom Bamboo tablet works, but is not detected in settings

Tags: drivers, tablet, wacom

I have a Wacom Bamboo tablet (CTH-460-DE) that I am trying to use in 14.04. The tablet actually works, has pressure sensitivity, etc., but does not show up when I open the Wacom tablet settings. It says "No tablet detected, please turn on or plug in your Wacom tablet" even though it is plugged in and actually working, and shows up in lsusb.

I've tried updating the drivers, rebooting, and the steps shown in this [How to get Bamboo Pad working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04) thread, but it still is not showing up in settings. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I was able to find a workaround for the settings I need (mapping tablet to one monitor) here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1656089

However, the tablet is still not showing up in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type `xinput list`. Does your device show up there?

Also can you check in *Settings*, *Devices*, *Wacom Tablet*? Can you see a button at the top to switch between *Stylus* and *Tablet*? For my Wacom Intuos2 the Tablet shows up (allowing one to alter monitor mapping settings) but the Stylos still does not.

[image]